# What is xmlns in every WPF file?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml

What is `xmlns`?

What role does it play in an XAML file when we create a WPF project?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

xmlns is an XML, not necessarily XAML, construct which defines a namespace in which to resolve xml element names.  Because it is defined without a qualifier, it is defining the default namespace by which an XML element name should be resolved.

In XAML you usually see the following entry.  It defines the default namespace to be essentially WPF and all XML element names are hence resolved as WPF elements.

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

It's also common to see non-default namespaces such as the following.

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

This defines a qualified namespace for XAML specific elements.  If you want an element or attribute name to be resolved within this namespace you should qualify it with x.  For example

```
<StackPanel x:Name="foo" />
```

There are 2 name resolutions in this definition.

1. StackPanel - Because it's an unqualified name, it will be resolved in the default namespace which is WPF
2. x:Name - Name is qualified with x and will be resolved within the XAML document.

Answer (score 25):

And you use xmlns to get a reference to your own namespaces within your XAML as well.  One of the first things I do when creating a new WPF project is to add a reference to the project namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfProject"
```

Now I have access to any classes I may create within my project (like IValueConverters and DataTemplateSelectors) by using the "local:" prefix

```
<local:BooleanToColorConverter x:Key="booleanToColorConverter" DefaultBrush="Green" HighlightBrush="Red" />
```

Of course, you don't have to use "local", you can name it whatever you want.  And you can add references to any other namespace you need the same way.

Answer (score 12):

You can also map multiple CLR namespaces together into one XML namespace by adding `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` to your assemblies. This is what the WPF team did, by mapping a lot of namespaces under System.Windows like this:

```csharp
[XmlnsDefinitionAttribute(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", 
    "System.Windows.Controls")]
[XmlnsDefinitionAttribute(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", 
    "System.Windows.Ink")]
```

This syntax can simplify your XAML, but be careful not to have classes with the same name in the CLR namespaces you merge together.

Answer (score 6):

As taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx)
The root element also contains the attributes xmlns and xmlns:x. These attributes indicate to a XAML processor which XML namespaces contain the element definitions for elements that the markup will reference. The xmlns attribute specifically indicates the default XML namespace.

This usage of xmlns to define a scope for usage and mapping is consistent with the XML 1.0 specification.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

#### Explanation via Intuitive Analogy

What role does  `xmlns` play in an XAML file?

It's to do with namespacing.

#### What do you mean by namespacing?

This is perhaps best explained via an analogy: Have you ever been in a situation where two people exist in the same group / company / circle - with the same name?

e.g. There was another "Ben" in our company.

If the boss yelled our name(s) - who would  respond?

In order to solve this conflicting issue, the boss called us: "Ben K" and "Ben M" respectively. i.e. there was now a 'namespace'.

Namespacing is kinda the same thing with WPF:

```xml
xmlns:k="http://koshy"
xmlns:m="http://mercury"
```

So now when the boss referred to one of us, there would be no confusion - `k` would mean me, and 'm' would mean the other Ben:

```
<b:GetBackToWork/> 
This would mean BenKoshy

<m:GetBackToWork/> 
This would mean Ben Mercury
```

The relevant `GetBackToWork` classes would be instantiated as a result, each from a different namespace. This is especially useful if you are referring to custom controls in another dll.