# What does xmlns:dc mean in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What does `xmlns:dc` mean in C# WPF XAML code? Can't find anything on it. Is it directory context? Domain controller?

Sorry for missing context.

I know xmlns is just xaml name space, but i want to know what dc stands for, like what does it mean?

```
xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:SomethingHere;assembly=SomethingHere"
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context.  Can you paste the whole XAML, or at least the relevant portion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630468/what-is-xmlns-in-every-wpf-file

Comment: @FlatEric -- Maybe I misinterpreted, but I don't think the question is about `xmlns`, rather about the `dc` namespace itself, no?

Comment: @roryap: it can be interpreted in both ways, you're right. I hope the author will clarify this

Comment: To me, xmlns:dc sounds like just another namespace alias given to the user created assembly. SInce there is nothing like that in WPF. Perhaps OP is new to WPF and referring some demo app where demo controls (dc?) assembly is referenced in view.

Comment: Oh I think it stands for DemoControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"dc" is an arbitrary prefix - it is used to reference the namespace as a short hand way, but can be anything you like.

Here's the explanation by the guy who thought it up:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html

Comment: THANK YOU, this is what I'm looking for

Comment: It's strange he chose "dc" because it's not quite clear the abbreviation you know?

Answer (score 0):

dc would just be the namespace of a control you're trying to use, so if you wanted to use a control called ThisControl that was inside the assembly "clr-namespace:SomethingHere;assembly=SomethingHere" you would need to use dc:ThisControl in the xaml.

Comment: What does dc stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Working with Cytoscape I have found that xmlns:dc refers to XLM Namespace(xlmns) and the Dublin Core(dc) metadata standard:

https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/

When exporting xgmml from cytoscape, part of the xml refers to http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ which redirects to the url above.

Example:

```
<graph id="78" label="TAPBPL" directed="1" cy:documentVersion="3.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cy="http://www.cytoscape.org" xmlns="http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML">
```